# Preserve list values during list-to-set conversion in Python

Tags: python, list, set

When one converts a list to a set in Python using the `set()` function, Python tries to simplify the set by removing repeated values from the list, as in the following example.

```
In [1]: list = [1,4,1]

In [2]: list
Out[2]: [1, 4, 1]

In [3]: set = set(list)

In [4]: set
Out[4]: {1, 4}
```

This is inconvenient when using sets to calculate properties of the list and converting back, as in the following vector subtraction example.

```
In [1]: a = [1,1,1]

In [2]: a
Out[2]: [1, 1, 1]

In [3]: b = [1,2,3]

In [4]: b
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3]

In [5]: list( set(a) - set(b) )
Out[5]: []
```

Clearly something went wrong: we were expecting the operation `{1-1, 1-2, 1-3} = {0, -1, -2}`. Instead, we have the following stored values.

```
In [6]: set(a)
Out[6]: {1}

In [7]: set(b)
Out[7]: {1, 2, 3}
```

This means we are calculating `{1-1, ?-2, ?-3} = ?`, which cannot be done.

Is there a way to retain the structure and values of a list when converting to a set in order to avoid this problem?

Clearly I am not talking about subtracting lists: I am talking about subtracting sets.

Comment: Why do you need sets for a vector subtraction?

Comment: Why were you expecting set subtraction to translate to numeric subtraction? The [documentation for sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) shows clearly that `-` is used for *set difference*. Any element in `set(a) - set(b)` produces a *new* set with all elements in `set(a)` that are *not* present in `set(b)`. Since `set(a)` only contains `1`, and `1` is in `set(b)` too, you get an empty set.

Comment: vectors are not sets, and sets are the *wrong tool* for vector operations.

Comment: *Python tries to simplify the set by removing repeated values from the list*. No, sets are unordered collections of unique values. There is no 'try' here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the need for `set` in this case. You can just `zip` the lists and do a subtraction like this

```
>>> a = [1,1,1]
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> [x-y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
[0, -1, -2]
```

Comment: You don't need the explicit cast to `list`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thanks, edited

Comment: Or simply don't try to reinvent the wheel :) - https://gist.github.com/mcleonard/5351452